# keyclaok 20.0.1 : How to import realm from json file?

Tags: keycloak

From the [documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/server/importExport) one can read:

> bin/kc.[sh|bat] start --import-realm
>
> When you set the --import-realm
> option, the server is going to try to import any realm configuration
> file from the **data/import** directory. Each file in this directory
> should contain a single realm configuration. Only regular files using
> the .json extension are read from this directory, sub-directories are
> ignored.

Where to put my .json file ? they are saying **data/import**, but where exactly ?

**PS: I'm not running keycloak in a docker container**

Comment: For the published containers, the import directory is `/opt/keycloak/data/import`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the root of the Keycloak project create the folder `data/import` and add your data into it.